# Стандарты написания кода на C

Tags: c, стандарт

Есть ли какой нибудь стандарт, категорически не рекомендующий мне такое написание кода:

```
int main(void) {
    float args[3];
    printf("1st arg: "); scanf("%f", &args[0]);
    printf("2nd arg: "); scanf("%f", &args[1]);
    printf("3rd arg: "); scanf("%f", &args[2]);
    printf("\nArgs: %.2f, %.2f, %.2f\n", args[0], args[1], args[2]); 
    return 0;   
}
```

Я имею ввиду `printf` и `scanf` в одной строке кода.

Comment: Почему бы не циклом

Comment: Удачи, с пошаговой отладкой!

Comment: Можно ещё через запятую все это написать, чтоб отладка медом не казалась :)

Comment: По сути, в ИДЕ в которой пишите, примените форматирование кода, и все станет на место и вопросов не будет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никакой **стандарт** не говорит ничего о **стиле** написания.

Пока вы работаете один - это вообще ваше дело. Просто при плохом стиле вы сами быстро начнете путаться в своем коде...

Когда вы работаете в команде - следует работать так, как принято в команде.

Есть не более чем *советы*, принимать которые или нет - ваше дело.

Словом, не волнуйтесь и поступайте так, как вам удобно и понятно :)

P.S. И не забывайте комментировать свой код - через месяц вы даже со своими исходниками будете с трудом вспоминать, что же вы тут хотели...

Comment: У многих языков есть общеизвестный или даже официальный style guide, а для C я видел только пару очень чудных и судя по всему мало применимых варианта. Интересно, почему так?

Answer (score 2):

Смысл любого стиля написания программ в том, что он должен сделать текст программы более легким для понимания, особенно другими людьми. Текст программы воспринимается гораздо лучше, когда она форматируется единообразно, по каким-то известным правилам.

Но это тем не менее не библейские скрижали, и если в каком-то случае небольшое отклонение от принятого стиля улучшит понимание программы, то такое отклонение полностью оправдано. Операторы должны писаться по одному в строке, но в некоторых случаях группировка нескольких операторов улучшит читаемость и понимаемость. В вашем конкретном случае написание `printf` и `scanf` в одной строке это совершенно правильный шаг.

Answer (score 2):

Да, вот например NASA С Style guide прямо запрещает использовать более одного выражения в строке, делая исключение для блоков `for`:

> **7.1.1 Statement  Placement**
>   Put only one statement per line (except in for loop statements)

Comment: Интересно, что за исключение сделано для "for loop statements". Что имеется в виду? Или они в NASA просто перепутали "expressions" и "statements"?

Answer (score -1):

В дополнение к вышеприведенным ответам, посоветую вам такую утилиту как `clang-format` которая позволяет автоматически формотировать код в соответсвии с выбранным стандартом (`google`, `llvm` и другие). Она прекрасно интегрируется с чем угодно, можно использовать с `git` или с какой-нибудь `IDE`. И можно забыть, про ручное выравнивание кода, подгонку под 80 столбцов и т.п. - все за вас сделает эта утилита.

Comment: Никто не пояснит за что минус?